# VLC video converting for Xoom

Tags: video, motorola-xoom

I have a mkv HD video and I'm trying to watch it on my motorola xoom. I found some players but none of them was good enough to play my video smoothly. Then I read on the internet that I need to convert my video to mp4 in a certain format but I can't find a free converter that can do that for me.

So I found out that VLC can convert the video for me but it takes too much time. I would like to know if someone have already converted hd videos using vlc and it played fine on the Xoom or if you have a better alternative free solution (I'm on a mac, so it'd be good to have a solution for mac).

Comment: Video transcoding always takes a long time.

Comment: Somone suggested that mailing yourself the video might get google to do the hard work for you. I've not tried it, but should be easy to test.

Comment: @syntheticbrain Can I email me a 2gb file? don't think so

Comment: Trying to convert it using VLC right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) - a multiplatform open-source video transcoder. It has quite user-friendly graphical interface, and supports different device profiles (you can roll your own as well). As to what settings to use on your Xoom: [Here](http://forum.androidcentral.com/motorola-xoom/62964-ripping-movies-2.html#post646878) someone managed to find the correct settings to make their Xoom play the transcoded video.

Some extra googling would probably give you additional information how to set the device profile in Handbrake -- seems a lot of people are trying to transcode video on this tablet.

Comment: For reference, I've tried Handbrake-transcoded video on my device (HTC Desire), and it worked fine without much tinkering, but YMMV.

Comment: The VLC converting didn't worked. Trying the Handbreak now.

Answer (score 0):

avconv (libav tools) does the job perfectly, and relatively fast. It's a command level tool, I use it on Linux but I don't know if there is a Mac version. I have converted several captured TV movies (.ts format) to MPEG4 x264, at 2000 bitrate. On the XOOM side, MX-player plays it nicely, VLC (Beta version) chokes on it. 
Here is a sample conversion command:
avconv -i infile.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -crf 23 outfile.mp4